# Changing variable name in Spyder or Notepad++

Tags: variables, replace, notepad++, spyder

I'm working with Spyder (for Python) and I'm looking for a way to change a variable name in the entire code. I know the replace-text-function, but this changes also text, where my variable name is only part of it. I know this function from Matlab, is there something like this in Spyder or alternatively in Notepad++?

So if I like to change the name of my variable "data", it should replace everything, where data is used (also expressions like data.append), but should not change things like "datanew", which is another variable

Comment: Could you add some sample lines and expected result? If `data` is present in a comment, do you want to change it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to well understand your needs, but I guess you want (using Notepad++):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bdata\b`
- Replace with: `new_name`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b      : word boundary, make sure we don't have a word character before
data    : literally "data"
\b      : word boundary, make sure we don't have a word character after
```

[Learn more on wordboundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html)

In order to keep `"data"`, you could use [negative lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!["'])\bdata\b(?!["'])
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. Even though it changes "data" as well, if it is a normal string/word in a comment, I think this is the best possible solution

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The technical term for this kind of operation is *refactoring*, and I'm sorry to tell you but Spyder doesn't have support for it as of November/2017.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with following regex in Notepad++

```
(?:"(?:\\.|[^\"])*")\K|(?:\bdata\b)
```

but there ist one handicap - it gives a match for the emptystring behind every closing " too.

So you can use it in 3 steps

1. replace `(?:"(?:\\.|[^\"])*")\K|(?:\bdata\b)` with `a_string_you_dont_use`
2. replace `"a_string_you_dont_use` with `"`
3. replace `a_string_you_dont_use` with your new variablename

tested with: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ExsC8n/1)

Maybe someone can improve the regex so that you can do it in one step. The first part matches everyhing inside `""`and drops the match with `\K` but it leaves an empty match. The second part matches the variable itself.

The regex takes care of `"` and `\"` but not of `'` so if you use it you have to extend the regex.